# How does BufferedReader readline work in a continous program?

Tags: java, process

So I know I can use readline to get the program output line by line but if I use a while loop

```
String l;
 while( (l=input.readLine()) != null)
    rcv = rcv + l
 return rcv;
```

But this  freezes my program until the external process finishes giving output. I want to listen to the output as the external process gives it. It can take a long time for the external program to exit.

I tried using read() but it also freezes my program until the end. How can I read the output, whatever is available and then do my processing? and then go back to read output again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a separate thread to read the input stream. The idea is that the blocking operations should happen in a separate thread, so your application main thread is not blocked.

One way to do that is submitting a `Callable` task to an executor:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> processOutput = executor.submit(() -> {
           // your code to read the stream goes here
           String l, rcv;
           while( (l=input.readLine()) != null) { ... }
           return rcv;
        });
```

This returns a ["future"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which is a way to represent a value that may not be available now but might be at some point in the future. You can check if the value is available now, or wait for the value to be present with a timeout, etc.

Comment: How many values can the future store? Is it possible to have a list of string in case of multiple values? Can I clear them as soon as I read them?

Comment: A Future holds one value. Sure you can make that one value a List. It sounds like you want a stream that processes lines as they come in. You can do that in the separate thread that you are starting. If you want to communicate results to the main thread, you can do that with a queue, for example ArrayBlockingQueue. The reader thread puts stuff into the q, other thread polls it